# ASP.NET Core Ajax File Parallel Upload causes Server to return same results twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this Dropzone declaration below. The problem I have now is that when I submit the form with multiple files to the server, it will not take it as one request but multiple requests going in. That is why when the server returns a response, I get duplicate results. Am I able to change anything on the javascript code or serverside to prevent this from happening? Is this something wrong with Dropzone instead?

To be clear: When I upload 1 file, I get 1 response from the server. This is correct. When I upload 3 files, I get 9 responses from the server because the server takes it as each request carrying 3 files 3 times. This is wrong

Attached is an example

[image]

```
<script>
    Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
        url:"@Url.Action("Save", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        addRemoveLinks: true, 
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 100,
        init: function (e) {
            var results = Array();
            var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit");
            var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
            var wrapperThis = this;
            submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                console.log("submitted");
                wrapperThis.processQueue();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                return false;
            });

            this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                console.log("Added file");
            }),

            this.on('sendingmultiple', function (data, xhr, formData) {
                formData.append("__RequestVerificationToken",token);
                formData.append("CategoryId", $("#CategoryId").val());
                formData.append("RepositoryId", $("#RepositoryId").val());
            });;

            this.on('error', function (file, message) {
                toastr.error(message);
                console.log(message);
            });

            this.on('success', function (file, message) {
                //toastr.success(message);
                console.log(message);
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Here is my server code:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Save(UploadDocumentViewModel Input)
{
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult(null);
    List<string> uploadResults = new List<string>();
    var repo = repositoriesData.Get(Input.RepositoryId);
    if (repo != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Request.Form.Files)
        {
            var file = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(item.ContentDisposition);
            var fileName = file.FileName.Trim('"');

            var fullFilePath = Path.Combine(repo.Path, fileName);

            SaveDocumentViewModel sdvm = new SaveDocumentViewModel
            {
                ApplicationName = configuration["ApplicationConfiguration:Name"],
                ApplicationSecretKey = configuration["ApplicationConfiguration:SecretKey"],
                DocumentCategoriesId = Input.CategoryId,
                Name = fileName,
                Filetype = item.ContentType,
                Link = Url.Content("~" + RepositoryManager.GetRequestPath() + "/" + repo.Name + "/" + fileName),
                Location = fullFilePath,
            };
            var documentId = documentsData.Save(sdvm);
            if (documentId != null)
            {
                documentCategoriesData.ProcessFile(Input.CategoryId, documentId, fileName);

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fullFilePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await item.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
                uploadResults.Add(fileName + " " + LoggingGlobals.Upload);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(LoggingGlobals.UploadFailed);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest(LoggingGlobals.UploadFailed);
    }
    return Ok(uploadResults);
}
```

Comment: It looks like the code somehow adds a new event listener for each file, which means after you have added three files, they get submitted three times. Can you put `console.log("event added")` in your submit listener callback and check if it gets called multiple times?

Comment: I checked. It doesn't get sent 3 times thats the strange part. If you see in my code, the console.log(submitted) gets called once only.

Comment: So the JS code only sends a single POST request, right? Or does the server actually *store* the files three times? Because if it works as it should on the server-side, the only question is why the JS code logs the success message three times.

Comment: The JS code sends one POST request. That means serverside its fine but just locally its registering 3 separate POST sent instead of 1 for some reason.

Comment: Try using the `queuecomplete` event instead of `success`.

Comment: I get undefined returned if I use queuecomplete

Comment: Are you logging the first or the second parameter? Did you try `this.on("queuecomplete", function (message) { console.log(message); });`?

Comment: my code is exactly the same as yours. Its still returning undefined. I guess that could work. However, my errors are also duplicated for some reason.

Comment: Right, so 1) the "queuecomplete" callback receives no arguments? 2) it's called multiple times? Right? Or what do you mean by "duplicated errors"? I'm about to move on; if you still want my help, please be clear so I don't have to keep asking about details.

Comment: I think I found the solution. I had to use "successmultiple" and "errormultiple" for some reason that causes it to work properly.